# Trying to run ols_correlations but keep running into an error message

Tags: r

I'm a Mac user and currently running R on version 1.1.463.

Trying to run ols_correlations to get zero-order, part, and semi-partial correlations but keep getting an error message saying,

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :   '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

Here's the code I ran...

```
SATV <-  c(500, 550, 450, 400, 600, 650, 700, 550, 650, 550)
HSGPA <- c(3.0, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 3.2, 3.8, 3.9, 3.8, 3.5, 3.1)
FGPA <-  c(2.8, 3.0, 2.8, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.5, 3.7, 3.4, 2.9)
scholar <- data.frame(SATV, HSGPA, FGPA)
model1 <- lm(HSGPA ~SATV, data = scholar)
ols_correlations(model1)
```

I'm getting the same error message every time I run the code even with a different dataset.
I could get the zero-order, partial, and semi-partial correlations using cor, pcor, spcor functions from ppcor library but I'm not sure why the ols_correlations function is not working for me. Please help.

Comment: I think it's failing because your model has only two variables

Answer (score 0):

Whenever facing unclear behavior/documentation, just check the source code. In this case, it is object-oriented programming so it might be a bit harder to figure it out. The source code for the function in question can be seen here (https://github.com/rsquaredacademy/olsrr/blob/master/R/ols-correlations.R).
First thing is to replicate the error. I did the following:

```
SATV <-  c(500, 550, 450, 400, 600, 650, 700, 550, 650, 550)
HSGPA <- c(3.0, 3.2, 2.8, 2.5, 3.2, 3.8, 3.9, 3.8, 3.5, 3.1)
FGPA <-  c(2.8, 3.0, 2.8, 2.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.5, 3.7, 3.4, 2.9)
scholar <- data.frame(SATV, HSGPA, FGPA)
model <- lm(HSGPA ~ SATV, data = scholar)


corm2 <- function(model) {
  
  mdata <- cordata(model)
  n     <- ncol(mdata)
  r2    <- c()
  
  for (i in 2:n) {
    out <- rtwo(i, mdata)
    r2  <- c(r2, out)
  }
  
  return(r2)
}
cordata <- function(model) {
  ols_prep_avplot_data(model)
}
rtwo <- function(i, mdata) {
  dat <- mdata[, c(-1, -i)]
  summary(lm(mdata[[1]] ~ ., data = dat))[[8]]
}
ols_prep_avplot_data <- function(model) {
  m1 <- as.data.frame(model.frame(model))[1]
  m2 <- as.data.frame(model.matrix(model))[, -1]
  as.data.frame(cbind(m1, m2))
}

corm2(model)
```

Then follow the functions until you isolate the error. In this case, the issue is at the for loop of corm2 that assumes that there are more than 2 independent variable (like @ Abdessabour Mtk suggested in his comment). Actually, you can see this easily employing the provided example in the documentation:

```
library(olsrr)
model <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp + wt + qsec, data = mtcars)
ols_correlations(model)

model <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp + wt, data = mtcars)
ols_correlations(model)

model <- lm(mpg ~ disp + hp, data = mtcars)
ols_correlations(model)
```